# Variable based on three possible conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a simple exam app in React where user answers questions and gains a score at the end. I want to display an appropriate smiley reflecting the success of the test.

So if the score is 75% and higher, the user will see a green smiley, if it's below 75% and above 40%, they'll get a yellow smiley and if it's below 40% they'll get a red smiley.

Now I have an image component prepared which will receive a string for its src prop.
The string looks like this:

`../assets/images/smiley_${smileyValue}.svg`

where smileyValue would be a string generated based on the score value I provide. How do I write the smileyValue variable that will supply the appropriate string "green", "yellow" or "red" based on the value I provide to it? I know I could write a function with an if/else chain but I'm curious if I can just do this all in a variable without a need to call anything.

Comment: Consider using if statements?

Comment: If each image is allocated a consistent colour, I don't see why you would need the colour's name as a string, just apply the colour to the SVG file?

Comment: [without a need to call anything](https://jsbin.com/hujuniyino/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

I would personally keep it very simple and just store all the possible values in an object/array, something like:

```js
const scoreSmileys = [
    [75, "../assets/images/smiley_green.svg"],
    [40, "../assets/images/smiley_yellow.svg"],
    [0, "../assets/images/smiley_red.svg"],
]

const score = 68;
const smiley = scoreSmileys.find(([limit]) => limit <= score)[1]
```

Even though using an object to store `scoreSmileys` might have felt more natural, JavaScript does not allow using integer keys, and it would have converted them to strings.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that keys in JS objects can only be strings.